# I don't understand how Google Play Games Services work?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have tried to follow to Google documentation for Google Play Services but that's impossible, because Google documentation is the worst ever.

Anyway, I manged to setup project and add Google Play Services in my app, but I don't know how to keep connected state of player when user changes activity.

I have **MainActivity**, where **extend BaseGameActivity**, and then user click on button Play, I open **GameActivity**, where I play game, and when I finish game I want to submit score to Google Play Services **Leaderboard**, but I can't because it seems that I am not connected.

I extend MyActivity with BaseGameActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends BaseGameActivity
```

Then I on **GameActivity** extend this:

```
public GameActivity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener
```

And then on **onCreate** use this:

```
  // Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getApplicationContext())
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();
```

And then when I finish game I try to submit score, but it seems that I am not connected.

```
  if(mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()){
                Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient,
                        getString(R.string.app_name));
                Games.Leaderboards.submitScore(mGoogleApiClient,
                        getString(R.string.number_guesses_leaderboard),
                        clickCounter);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/training/signin), you need to call `mGoogleApiClient.connect()` aswell. They recommend using a button for sign in, but you can also do it at `onStart()`:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

If all goes well you'll receive the callback `onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)` which you are already implementing.

Answer (score 1):

Play Game Services are really made with Fragments in mind. It is almost mandatory to use Fragments instead of Activities, and to have a single Activity in your app...

Comment: Do you have any example beside of Google documentation?

Comment: Nope, I dont. But I don't really understand why say the documentation is "the worst ever". It is kinda nicely done. Did you use the samples as a base, as it's recommanded on the documentation ? https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/games.html

Comment: I have opens new question based on sample from documentation, but I still get error with sign in. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804929/failed-to-sign-in-please-check-your-network-connection-and-try-again