# Failed to sign in error in google play games on some phones

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, multiplayer

I am developing an app that implements the google play games turn based multiplayer api.App works fine in my phone while I was developing and I could sign into multiplayer. But when I tested my app in another phone with same features and configurations, it shows error:

**Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again.**

I am not positive if this has anything to do with my phone using my gmail account which is the developer account and the second phone using another gmail that is listed as a testing account for the app. I have the app in the alpha stage of testing but to put the app on the second phone I just physically hooked it up to my laptop like I did with my own phone.

I have made sure that I am connected to the wifi and I am able to navigate just fine. There is no issue with my connection.

Please let me know if you think you need more information. I appreciate the help.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check your network connection and try again. have you check your network connectivity ?

Comment: @AnkitMakwana Yes my network connection is fine.

Comment: can you provide full logcat and some code? Give a [try to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16601346/2591002)

Comment: @SweetWisher The logcat shows nothing but the connection failed and I don't know what code would even be relevant in this case.

Comment: have you [checked this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26819268/2591002) ?

Comment: I am not sure but i just found this. it's weird but you can at least check [_If the phone has the wrong time/date you will get this message._](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-m/280372-google-play-says-theres-no-connection.html#post2806501) @saboehnke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give a try by setting correct date time

If they are set to *Automatic*, set them manually.

If you still face same issue after doing this, [follow this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804929/failed-to-sign-in-please-check-your-network-connection-and-try-again/26819268#26819268)

Reference Link : [Google Play says there's no connection](http://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-m/280372-google-play-says-theres-no-connection.html#post2806501)

Hope it helps ツ

Comment: I tried the date and time option and it didn't work. My issue with the second thing you mentioned is that I don't know where the release keystore is. I have already done the other things mentioned in that post.

Comment: have you generated release keystore?? You must get it

Comment: I am not positive how to get it.And i didn't think i would need to yet since this is not being released yet. Its still in testing.

Comment: Is your game published, in alpha or beta?

Comment: You have to do *Delete all client ids and add again client ids for debug keystore and release keystore.*

Comment: It is in alpha. I didn't think that it would make a difference since I am just loading up the app on the phone physically from the laptop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68316/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-saboehnke).

Answer (score 0):

Just add your email id too in 'Add Testers' field and wait for 2-3 minutes.

Go to 'Google Play Developer Console', Click on 'Testing' and add email ids of all tester including developers.