# Google play game service "Failed to sign in.Please check your network connection and try again"

Tags: google-play-services

I just released my app on google play. When the app tries to login to google game service, I get an pop saying "Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again". I have been able to login during the development of the app.

In google developer console, I have linked both the debug and release version of my app.

One thing that might be the problem is that I published the app before the game service (which is not recommended by google). Is this the problem? How do I fix this? How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

As referred with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812464/failed-to-sign-in-error-in-google-play-games-on-some-phones) and from this [forum](https://forums.androidcentral.com/droid-razr-m/280372-google-play-says-theres-no-connection.html#post2806501), if the phone has the wrong time/date you will encounter this error. You may also check the answer in [Failed to sign in. Please check your network connection and try again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804929/failed-to-sign-in-please-check-your-network-connection-and-try-again/26819268#26819268). *I have moved app id and leaderboard id from strings.xml to ids.xml in values folder. I have deleted all client ids and add again client ids for debug keystore and release keystore.* Hope this helps!